# How to keep mod_rewrite from recognizing directories

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string, directory

So, lately I've been dealing with an issue relating to mod_rewrite and it seems nobody is trying to do anything like it. Every question people have is about trying to **exclude** directories from the rewrite, when I want them to be **included** like any other.

For instance, assuming my root directory with .htaccess file in it is `www.example.com/root/`

When I type in made up directory, such as `www.example.com/root/asdfasdf`, I have my .htaccess file set to redirect me to `www.example.com/root/index.php?url=asdfasdf` without change what's in the address bar on my browser

However, in trying to do the same with a **real** directory, such as `www.example.com/root/admin`, it not only changes the url in the address bar but changes it to `www.example.com/root/admin/?url=admin`.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on. I've tried all kinds of different regular expressions and flags and the ones that redirect anything still cause this same issue. can I go to `www.example.com/root/admin` and still get redirected to the root folder while hiding that the query string is `?url=admin`.

**[UPDATE: additional information 11-30-2012]**

Like I said, I've tried it will multiple different lines of code and come out with the exact same redirect issue, assuming the redirect doesn't just fail altogether and produce a 500 error. Here's one of my latest iterations, though, which has produced the issue of not ignoring direcotories.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.\*\\.("png"|"jpg"|"gif") [NC]
RewriteRule (.\*?) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

The rewrite condition is to keep the engine from rewriting if a picture is being requested (for css and img tags). I only didn't mention it previously because I have tried removing that line and it has made no difference.

I'm not exactly a master of mod_rewrite, though, so if you see any errors with anything I've written, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to do and it would have been helpful to see what your .htaccess file actually looked like. However the following lines in an .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root/index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) /root/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Will silently redirect requests made to `http://www.example.com/root/madeupfolder/madeupfile.php` to `http://www.example.com/root/index.php?url=madeupfolder/madeupfile.php` and will also do the same for real folders. So if the folder admin exists under root, then requests to `http://www.example.com/root/admin` will be silently redirected to `http://www.example.com/root/index.php?url=admin`

If however you wanted to serve up folders and files that actually exist, but rewrite requests for folders and files that do not exist, then you would need to adjust the rewrite like so

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root/index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) /root/index.php?url=$1 [R=301]
```

This would still rewrite requests made to `http://www.example.com/root/madeupfolder/madeupfile.php` to `http://www.example.com/root/index.php?url=madeupfolder/madeupfile.php`, but for real folders and files, such as requests made to `http://www.example.com/root/admin`, the admin folder would be served up.

Hope this helps, but if you can clarify your question a bit then I can try and help again.

Comment: I guess I never got around to actually trying your suggestion. I exchanged [L] with [QSA,L] in your code and now it works perfectly! Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: Actually, after a bit of testing, I found that this only works the way I want **if** the redirect is with the "Sites" folder on a mac. It doesn't work right in the regular localhost htdocs folder in XAMPP. I'll have to keep researching a bit, but this at least verifies that my code should work.